# How to install downloaded Python packages without sudo?

Tags: python

I need to install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PasteScript on a VM without sudo access ([this one](https://github.com/tog22/eaforum/blob/master/Vagrantfile), if relevant). I've downloaded it but when I run `python setup.py install` I get:

> running install Checking .pth file support in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ error: can't create or remove
>   files in install directory
>
> The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in
>   the installation directory:
>
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-1621.pth'
>
> The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix,
>   or the distutils default setting) was:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
>
> Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If
>   the installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need
>   to sign in as the administrator or "root" account.

One alternative suggestion I found was to use pip, but I can't install pip without sudo.

PS: There are many similar questions, but none (that I can find!

Comment: You can install locally with `pip` using `pip install XXXX --user`

Comment: also pip is available in python 2.7, but not in original 2.7 version. You may have to get hold of it first.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

As stated in the doc, it should work as you expect: https://docs.python.org/2/install/#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme

Comment: Is it OK for you? If yes, could you accept the answer please?